# Is there a way to create and apply a style to multiple elements in Compose like we do with CSS

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I have multiple rows filled with multiple texts and I need all those texts to have the same padding, color, font size and mostly everything else:

```
Row{
    for(i in 1..7) Text(stuff[i-1])
}
Row{
    for(i in 8..15) Text(stuff[i-1])
}
Row{
    for(i in 16..23) Text(stuff[i-1])
}
Row{
    for(i in 24..30) Text(stuff[i-1])
}
```

I really don't want to have bloated code with all the redundant modifiers repeating over and over, is there a way to use something like a CSS class and paste it onto every element I want?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jetpack Compose [Modifiers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers) are used for

1. Change the composable's size, layout, behavior, and appearance
2. Add information, like accessibility labels
3. Process user input
4. Add high-level interactions, like making an element clickable,
   scrollable, draggable, or zoomable

You can use a Modifier for multiple items

by declaring them globally or inside a function such as

```
val modifier = Modifier
    .shadow(1.dp, CircleShape)
    .border(1.dp, Color.Yellow)
    .size(100.dp)
    .background(Color.Red)
    .padding(10.dp)
```

or creating your own modifier

```
fun Modifier.myStyle() = this.then(
Modifier
        .shadow(1.dp, CircleShape)
        .border(1.dp, Color.Yellow)
        .size(100.dp)
        .background(Color.Red)
        .padding(10.dp)
)
```

Multiple Composable can use declared or Modifier extension functions

```
Row(modifier){}
Column(modifier){}
Row(modifier){}
Row(Modifier.myStyle()){}
Row(Modifier.myStyle()){}
```

However ***font size*** is not a general attribute you can apply to any Composable, specific attributes like this can be stored in a class for Composable. `Text` Composable stores its attributes in a class named `TextStyle` and this can be applied to any `Text` when you create an instance of `TextStyle`.

You can create your own data classes to store Composable specific attributes either.

```
data class MyAttributes(val fontSize:TextUnit=10.sp, val elevation = CardElevation.elevation,...,val sliderColors)
```

You can also use [CompositionLocal](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal) to pass specific styling to scope of Composables too

```
data class Elevations(val card: Dp = 0.dp, val default: Dp = 0.dp)

// Define a CompositionLocal global object with a default
// This instance can be accessed by all composables in the app
val LocalElevations = compositionLocalOf { Elevations() }


class MyActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            // Calculate elevations based on the system theme
            val elevations = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) {
                Elevations(card = 1.dp, default = 1.dp)
            } else {
                Elevations(card = 0.dp, default = 0.dp)
            }

            // Bind elevation as the value for LocalElevations
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalElevations provides elevations) {
                // ... Content goes here ...
                // This part of Composition will see the `elevations` instance
                // when accessing LocalElevations.current
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are my saviour, thank you very much Thracian! :)